# Как регулировать высоту границы(border) ?

Tags: css

Приветствую, вопрос  таков: как регулировать высоту границы(border)? Например, надо уменьшить ее высоту в  половину, возможно ли  это?

Answer (score 3):

Ширина бордера задаётся свойством [border](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border). В обычном CSS (который более-менее одинаково поддерживается везде) свойства можно только назначать или переназначать (например в одном месте определить border: 10px solid red, а потом в другом переопределить на border: 5px solid red), но нельзя например сделать в два раза меньше или в два раза больше независимо от исходного значения (border: border*2).

В черновиках CSS3 есть функция [calc()](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc) и кажется есть возможность обращаться к текущему значению свойств. Так-что в принципе наверное можно сделать рамку в два раза шире независимо от её исходной ширины, но не факт что это уже поддерживается браузерами (и это гарантированно не поддерживается старыми браузерами), не факт что эти части стандарта не изменятся радикально, и не факт что стандарт вообще будет утверждён.

Answer (score 0):

Важно:

Толщина (высота/ширина) рамки (бордера) должна быть кратной 1px.
Не допускается значение в 0,5px или 1,5px.

Comment: Поспешил плюсануть. Оказывается нет, значения округляются до целых.

Подробнее например тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/123537/html-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8